# Export a list of all Groups in G Suite

Tags: postman, google-admin-sdk

I need to export a list of groups in G Suite to compare with the source from a recent migration from another mail provider.  I'm stuck, trying to get Postman desktop client to connect via api to the Directory API of our g suite instance.
Basically I'm an API noob and have no idea how to get the two to talk.  I've setup an OAuth2 client ID and Secret, but not sure of what settings to use in Postman to get authentication up and running.  Using Authorization code or Client ID as the option for "Grant Type", either way I get a 401 error.
The only field I haven't entered anything in is the "Callback URL" not sure where to get it from.  Seeing mixed info in Google's documentation.  Do I need a service account or just the OAuth ID and secret? 
Closest I've gotten is: "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: /" using the Authentication code grant type. Left blank but I'm almost sure that is referring to the callback url.

What am I missing here? Or where do I find the callback URL if that is all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that should handle authorization and export a CSV of all your groups.

https://github.com/jmathai-google/all-groups-in-customer